# Installing Chrome or Firefox through PlayOnLinux

Tags: firefox, wine, google-chrome, playonlinux

I need a Windows install of a modern browser. I'm trying to install Chrome or Firefox, so I've been using PlayOnLinux.

**Firefox:**

I get the following error:

```
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.
```

However,

```
ll /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ | grep freetype
```

returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       21 Apr 13  2018 libfreetype.so.6 -> libfreetype.so.6.15.0

-rw-r--r--   1 root root   767576 Apr 13  2018 libfreetype.so.6.15.0
```

I've tried reinstalling both POL and FreeType, to no avail.

**Chrome**:

The installer runs, somewhat...
It seems the install needs an internet connection. I end up with a failure to connect to the internet message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need a Windows version of a browser or do you need a website to think you on windows?  There are quite a few extensions listed as 'user-agent switchers' that will make websites think you are using Windows or Mac and/or a different browser.

Comment: I do not know, but thinking the 'wine' people do not try working on windows firefox/chrome to work with linux.  They have tried with windows IE.